# g++ can't override exit function

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have a c++ program where I want to compile out std::exit and use my own, i.e. via:

```
-Dexit=myExit
```

However, I run into this issue:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6352,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/sstream:38,
                 from tests/helpers.h:4,
                 from tests/helpers.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdlib:146:11: error: ‘::exit’ has not been declared
   using ::exit;
```

I'm running it on virtualBox: Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 / Debian 10

Comment: Who told you that this is something valid you can do in C++?

Comment: @Brian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199689/how-can-i-handle-exit-calls-in-3rd-party-library-code

I have also had it working in macOs but unfortunately I really need it in linux

Comment: The best way to do this is to just change the source code to call `myExit` directly.

Comment: @Cornstalks that is not an option in my case, I must be able to do it at compile time

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding `exit` on your own, which is non standard and risky, you could register your own functions to be executed at program exit using `atexit`.

`atexit` takes a function pointer parameter, `(void (*func)(void))`, and registers that function to be executed by `exit` (for reference, see [glibc exit.c source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/exit.c)).

With this approach, you could register multiple functions to be executed at exit, plus, `atexit` behaviour is well defined in the C++ standard.

For examples and documentation, see:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Cleanups-on-Exit.html

Comment: Unfortunately rather than 'extra' code being ran at exit, I would prefer the function exiting to instead throw an exception that can be caught. Raising an exception from an atexit regsiter still causes the program to terminate.

Comment: @jajabarr could you please explain, where the exception will be caught? Are you running with some special environment? I don't think the C++ runtime allows for exceptions at exit.